# Parallax scroll working on 1 image but not on other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on giving parallax effect to 2 of my background images and it is working on the first image but not on the second image..the code is as below

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function() {

        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            // scroll the background at var speed
            // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!

            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

        }); // end window scroll

    });

});
```

HTML :-

```
<section class="parallax" data-type="background" data-speed="5">
        <h2>Check out this cool parallax scrolling effect. Use these ribbons to display calls to action mid-page.</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info">PARALLAX</button>

    </section>
```

CSS:-

```
.parallax {
    height:35em;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463123081488-789f998ac9c4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=6d1a6d1c5a7eb63d0c411b1d019f0b30');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: 5em;
}

.parallax button {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
```

The weird part is that the second image does not show at all and shows only if I remove data-speed attribute but then the parallax does not work..I am stuck and confused so please assist..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using $window.scrollTop(), which will get bigger as you scroll down the page, and setting that relative to the top of the image container. Seems like you need to subtract the elements position from the top of the document first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function() {

    var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        // scroll the background at var speed
        // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!

        var yOffset = $bgobj.offset().top;
        var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop() - yOffset) / $bgobj.data('speed'));

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        // Move the background
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

    }); // end window scroll

});

});
```

Your first image is likely working as it's at the top of the page so the offset doesn't matter?

Comment: Thank you , it worked..If you don't mind can you please tell me what you did (as jquery is not a strong point for me)..

Comment: Sure, used $bgobj.offset() which returns an object with the x / y position of the element relative to the document, then subtracted that from the scrollTop() value, so the image yPos always starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(i,e) {
            // scroll the background at var speed
                // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!

                var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $(e).data('speed'));

                // Put together our final background position
                var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

                // Move the background
                $(e).css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
        });
    }); // end window scroll

});
```