# gap between navbar and header-image (background-image) due to parallax scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image][image]I was working on getting parallax for all my background images and I had an issue which was resolved by a stackoverflow community expert and got those to work but a small problem which I did not realize yesterday is that now I have a very thin white bar between the navbar and header-image and it has something to do with the parallax code ( because without the parallax code there is no gap ) so if somebody can check this and assist me it would be great..

jquery code :-

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $(function() {

// Cache the window object
var $window = $(window);

// Parallax background effect
// Tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641



$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function() {

    var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        // scroll the background at var speed
        // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!

        var yOffset = $bgobj.offset().top;
        var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop() - yOffset) / $bgobj.data('speed'));

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        // Move the background
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

    }); // end window scroll

});

});
```

HTML Code :-

```
<header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">FEATURES <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SHOP <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <section class="header-image" data-type="background" data-speed="5">
            <h1> Elegant Single Page WordPress theme</h1>
            <p>Easy , Reliable and Awesome</p>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-info">GET STARTED</button>

        </section>

    </header>
```

CSS code :-

```
.header-image {
    height:40em;
    background: url('../images/beach_sunset.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-image h1 {
    padding: 3em 0.5em 0;
}

.header-image p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.header-image h1,
.header-image p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-image button {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to check it? Thanks

Comment: No Problem..just a couple of minutes..

Comment: I have tried to create the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b1mcw8zm/5/

Comment: I didnt search for the reason, but if you change the h1-h3 margin-top from 20px to 0 px it is fixed.
`.h1, .h2, .h3, h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}`

Comment: the updated fiddle with an id added to the h1 to remove the margin [https://jsfiddle.net/1ht7vfhq/](https://jsfiddle.net/1ht7vfhq/)

Comment: The problem is still there..i will post the screenshot like I did for the first answer..

Comment: nogo..the issue is still there..the issue only vanishes when i remove the data-type="background" data-speed="5" from the section that has the class=header-image but then i have no parallax which is not acceptable to me , else everything is failing so if somebody can create that workaround the issue will be resolved..

Comment: try it like this [https://jsfiddle.net/1ht7vfhq/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/1ht7vfhq/1/)
I removed the var yOffset and gave the h1 margin-top: 0

Comment: removing yOffset will not work as i have another parallax background image on the screen and without this offset calculation happening , it will not render properly..please check this question i had asked a few days back..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364022/parallax-scroll-working-on-1-image-but-not-on-other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112902/discussion-between-seru-and-dhaval-chheda).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the yOffset wich was needed for another image on the page but not the one ontop of the page.
Fixed with using 2 different data-types, one using the yOffset and the other not using it.
tlrdr:
javascript calculation was incorrect for the image provided

Comment: you were awesome..hoping to get you again if I need assistance

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are combining both `padding` and `margin` properties. You have to beware with that. You can always combine them (for sure) but you have to be aware of the space that they will take.

`padding` is the space between the content and its container.

`margin` is the space between the container and the rest of elements.

If you inspect your webpage:

[image]

And here is your [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1mcw8zm/8/).

Just add

```
h1{
  margin: 0;
}
```

and it is done.

**Warning!:** Using type selector (`h1`) will remove the margin of all `h1` that you will have in your webpage. If you want only to remove the `margin` property in one `h1` only you should use an `ID` as @PRYM put in his answer.

Comment: Don't add h1{margin:0;} it will remove margin from all H1, which might break at some other place. Instaed only change the margin of the H1 I mentioned in my answer

Comment: nogo..the issue is still there..the issue only vanishes when i remove the data-type="background" data-speed="5" from the section that has the class=header-image but then i have no parallax which is not acceptable to me , else everything is failing so if somebody can create that workaround the issue will be resolved..

Comment: @PRYM Yes, you are right. It will remove the margin from all the `h1`. I guessed that the OP should know that. I will edit the question alerting about that. Sorry.

Comment: @DhavalChheda I am sorry but I cannot understand what do you mean with parallax. Have you seen my update JSFiddle? It removes the white space.

Comment: Parallax effect is when the background and the text above it move at different speed. I agree  that removing margins is how we have two block level elements touch each other but in my case the section which has the background image has a parallax effect for the background and hence the section has the data attributes in it and the only way that the navbar and section touch each other is if I remove those data attributes from the <section> bu then since i removed the data-attributes the section does not parallax effect any more..

Comment: @DhavalChheda I do not exactly understand what should be the effect but anyway you do not have any `data-type="background"` for your `section`. Look this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1mcw8zm/9/) and let me know if it is doing the effect that you are looking for.

Comment: may i know what you have changed so I that I can change that bit of code in my brackets and check

Comment: @DhavalChheda I just added `data-type` to the `section`.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Look at this another [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1mcw8zm/10/) and resize the screen. I think this could be the effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112904/discussion-between-error404-and-dhaval-chheda).

Answer (score 2):

The top margin of H1 tag which contains "Elegant Signle Page WordPress theme" is causing the gap.

Just adding margin-top:0px and it works

```
<h1 style="margin-top: 0px;"> Elegant Single Page WordPress theme</h1>
```

Comment: nogo..the issue is still there..the issue only vanishes when i remove the data-type="background" data-speed="5" from the section that has the class=header-image but then i have no parallax which is not acceptable to me , else everything is failing so if somebody can create that workaround the issue will be resolved..

Comment: The issue then is with your JS. When you are trying to adjust the coordinates of the image. Try playing with var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

Comment: i tried somethings but then I am getting errors so if you could give me an example of how to manipulate it , then I will try other values..